# Call to Url.RouteUrl not working on deployed website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

In an ASP MVC3 project a call to:-

```
<h2><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("_ScientificPrograms", new { idProgramaSeleccionado = @programa.Id, nombrePrograma = @programa.NombreProgramaUrl(), IdiomaSeleccion = idioma })">@programa.NombrePrograma(@idioma)</a></h2>
```

corresponding to a registered route in the Global.asax.cs file of:-

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "_ScientificPrograms", // Route name
             "{IdiomaSeleccion}/research/scientific-programmes/{idProgramaSeleccionado}/{nombrePrograma}/{idGrupoSeleccionado}/{nombreGrupo}", 
             new { controller = "Research", action = "ScientificProgrammes", IdiomaSeleccion = UrlParameter.Optional, idProgramaSeleccionado = UrlParameter.Optional, nombreGrupo = UrlParameter.Optional, idGrupoSeleccionado = UrlParameter.Optional, nombrePrograma = UrlParameter.Optional } 
         );
```

works fine running on my local machine producing urls like:-

```
http://localhost/es/research/scientific-programmes/1/molecular-oncology
```

When the website is deployed, however, the same call only produces

```
http://deployedsite/es/research/
```

although entering

```
http://deployedsite/es/research/scientific-programmes/1/molecular-oncology
```

does correctly resolve the page.

The same behaviour is observed both on my own test hosting and on my clients QA server. Other routing calls work fine but it appears that this one is some what special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the application of the latest .NET service packs to the server fixed the problem with no code changes.  The It-Works-On-My-Machine behaviour turned out to be the smoking gun.

Answer (score 2):

You likely have solved this or moved on, but I will put this information here in case someone else comes across your question because they are suffering from the same MVC3 bug that causes this issue.

It turns out that consecutive `UrlParameter.Optional` parameters causes a small bug in MVC3, as per [this blog entry from Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx/).

> The bug manifests when you have a route with two consecutive optional URL parameters and you attempt to use the route to generate an URL. The incoming request matching behavior is unchanged and continues to work fine.
>
> The workaround is simple. To fix this issue, change the existing route to not have any optional parameters by removing the default values for month and day. This route now handles the first URL where month and day was specified.
>   We then add a new route for the other two cases, but this route only has one optional month parameter.

In my case, I had a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "HouseholdComments",
            "Comments/Household/{id}/{saQid}/{clId}",
            new { controller = "Comments", action = "Household", id = UrlParameter.Optional, saQid = UrlParameter.Optional, clId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And I was trying to use Url.RouteUrl like this:

```
var questionHref = '@Url.RouteUrl("HouseholdComments", new {id=@Model.SafetyForm.SAS_SEQ_NO})'
```

thinking that it *should* just call the route with only 1 parameter. But it did not, it returned null. As in Phil's article above, I had to add a separate route for this case *after* my `HouseholdComments` route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "HouseholdCommentsBase",
            "Comments/Household/{id}",
            new {controller = "Comments", action="Household", id=UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

I then was able to use that route in `Url.RouteUrl` to properly get me the link I needed.

I'm guessing that you should just need to add another route to handle the case where you are only using only those 3 parameters in `Url.RouteUrl`.